# JQuery get subString?

Tags: jquery, substring

Script

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var referrer = document.referrer;  
    // referrer = http://localhost:49972/Enerji/Kompanzasyon 
    $("#uygula_buton").click(function () {
        if (referrer == "Enerji/Kompanzasyon") {
            //
        }else
        {
            //
        }
    });
});
```

referrer value is `http://localhost:49972/Enerji/Kompanzasyon`, But I want to get only controller and action name like this `Enerji/Kompanzasyon`. How to get this in jquery.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/PSXr4/#update)**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var referrer = document.referrer;  
    // referrer = http://localhost:49972/Enerji/Kompanzasyon 
    $("#uygula_buton").click(function () {
        ref = referrer.split('/')[3]+"/"+referrer.split('/')[4];
        if (referrer == ref ) {
            //
        }else
        {
            //
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
var referrer = "http://localhost:49972/Enerji/Kompanzasyon";

var split = referrer.split("//");

var index = split[1].indexOf("/");​​​  //gets first index of "/" in "localhost:49972/Enerji/Kompanzasyon"

alert(split[1].substring(index+1));
```

The result  [Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/4Pzh8/1/)

```
Enerji/Kompanzasyon
```

​

Answer (score 2):

you can use Split() function in js.

```
var refer = referrer.split();
```

and use `refer[2]` element.